# GoogleCloudMessaging integration on iOS using cocoapods

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, cocos2d-x, cocoapods

I'm trying to integrate GoogleCloudMessaging(GCM) on iOS project. (Cocos2d-x v3.2)
As per the google's instruction, (https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client)
I use cocoapods but failed with following error.

```
$ pod install
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `GoogleCloudMessaging` required by `Podfile`
```

Here are what I tested.

- install GCM on cocos2dx project (v3.2) -> failed.
- create a non-cocos2dx project and install GCM -> succeeded
- install GoogleAnalytics on cocos2dx project -> succeeded.
- create a cocos2dx project using v3.7 and install GCM -> failed.

I don't have any clue yet why installing GCM is failed but GoogleAnalytics is not. 
Is there anyone who succeed integrating GCM on iOS?

**EDIT**

This is my Podfile

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '6.0'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
target 'SampleApp iOS' do
        pod 'GoogleCloudMessaging'
end

target 'SampleApp Mac' do
end
```

Comment: Can you attach the contents of your podfile?

Answer (score 1):

I could solve this problem referring a post in cocos2d-x forum.
Changing Deployment Target to 7.0 or higher in Xcode project setting will clear this issue.

Comment: I was able to fix my issue by changing deployment target version as I described. I got the error when the version was set as 6.X. Try changing the version in Xcode.